# HttpAntiForgeryException is not present in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, antiforgerytoken

I am writing anti forgery validation for my .net core microservice and wondering whether the are any alternatives to HttpAntiForgeryException which exists in .Net Framework. In my .NET Core app I cannot find this type. Can I somehow enable it ? Or should I write my custom exception to throw ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET Core replaced it with a new exception: `AntiforgeryValidationException` in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery` namespace.